# Execution failed for task' :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. >Process 'command 'C:\dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have been facing this error since I upgrade my flutter version,

I tried some solutions but non of them work, my experience in this field is low I cant provide the right details so any thing will be helpful, Thank you...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. First try flutter clean and try to run
   if its not working then delete folder ".gradle" in your projectdir>android>.gradle, delete pubspec.lock  try flutter upgrade and run now